# 301 redirect directory with query parameters

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, http-status-code-301

I'd like to redirect everything in `/bar/` to a new subdomain but still pass in any query parametes from the original URL. E.g

Original URL examples:

1. http://www.foo.com/bar/
2. http://www.foo.com/bar/index.php
3. http://www.foo.com/bar/index.html
4. http://www.foo.com/bar/test.php?id=123&utm_source=google

Should redirect to:

1. http://bar.foo.com/
2. http://bar.foo.com/
3. http://bar.foo.com/
4. http://bar.foo.com/?id=123&utm_source=google

This is what I currently have:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^bar/?(.*)$ https://bar.foo.com/? [R=301,L]
```

However, it doesn't pass in the query parameters I need in the 4th example above. I know the `?` prevents query parameters being passed in so this will most likely need to be removed I assume but not sure what to replace it with?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a new rule like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^bar(/|$) https://bar.foo.com/ [NC,R=301,L]
```

`QUERY_STRING` will automatically be carried over to target URI.

Make sure there is no trailing `?` in the target URI which strips existing query string.

Comment: Thanks Ill try it now. Sorry I didn't mean to include the actual domain, can you please edit your answer please?

Comment: Thanks. ``http://www.foo.com/bar/index.php`` passes in /index.php so it redirects to http://bar.foo.com/index.php. I only need query parameters to be passed in.

Comment: Also, the 4th example seems to pass in ``/test.php`` instead of ``/?id=123&utm_source=google`` e.g ``https://bar.foo.com/test.php`` instead of ``http://bar.foo.com/?id=123&utm_source=google``

Comment: Sorry you may have updated your answer whilst I was commenting. I'm using http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/ to test by the way.

Comment: Ok don't test it there since its not reliable. Try last updated code directly on your webserver.